# Get carrier signal strength of Windows Phone programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, signal-strength

I am new on Windows Phone Technology,so I want to get Carrier Signal Strength of Windows Phone,I have seen many links but everyone says no API are available for calculating signal strength,but is there other way to find out signal strength or any third party API are available for windows phone ? Please help me to figure out the solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no API for that. If you take a look at [How to get network information for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202859%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [NetworkInterfaceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfaceinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you'll see that there is no information besides very limited amount.

Comment: thanks,but i can get Bandwidth from NetworkInterfaceInfo.Bandwidth so can I calculate signal strength from bandwidth value?